# Issue setting path in mac terminal

Tags: bash, macos, go, makefile, path

I am using VS code and mac terminal both for Go development.
In the VS code, I am able to run all the related build and setup because by Go is pointing to correct version as below:

```
$go version
go version go1.15.6 darwin/amd64

$which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

But in Terminal go version and GOROOT is showing something different as below:

```
$go version 
go1.16 darwin/amd64

$which go
/usr/local/bin/go
```

How to set correct path in terminal too?

Comment: You could update your `$PATH` by making sure that `/usr/local/go/bin` comes *before* `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

You need for the correct directory to preceed the default in the PATH environment variable.

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```